# Parsing through HTML with BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Currently my code is as follows:

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import requests

 main_url = 'http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/a-z'
 response = requests.get(main_url)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
 mylist = [t for tags in soup.find_all(class_='m-PromoList o-Capsule__m-
           PromoList') for t in tags if (t!='\n')]
```

As of now, I get a list containing the correct information but its still inside of HTML tags. An example of an element of the list is given below:

```
 <li class="m-PromoList__a-ListItem"><a href="//www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/ina-garten/16-bean-pasta-e-fagioli-3612570">"16 Bean" Pasta E Fagioli</a></li>
```

from this item I want to extract both the href link and also the following string separately, but I am having trouble doing this and I really don't think getting this info should require a whole new set of operations. How do?

Comment: Check the Beautiful Soup documentation. You can access the attributes of the tags such as `t.href` or `t.get("href", None)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to get href and text for one element:

```
href = soup.find('li', attrs={'class':'m-PromoList__a-ListItem'}).find('a')['href']
text = soup.find('li', attrs={'class':'m-PromoList__a-ListItem'}).find('a').text
```

For a list of items:

```
my_list = soup.find_all('li', attrs={'class':'m-PromoList__a-ListItem'})
for el in my_list:
    href = el.find('a')['href']
    text = el.find('a').text
    print(href)
    print(text)
```

**Edit:**
*An important tip to reduce run time:* Don't search for the same tag more than once. Instead, save the tag in a variable and then use it multiple times.

```
a = soup.find('li', attrs={'class':'m-PromoList__a-ListItem'}).find('a')
href = a.get('href')
text = a.text
```

In large HTML codes, finding a tag takes up lot of time, so doing this will reduce the time taken to find the tag as it will run only once.

Comment: what if theres two of the same tags, each with relevant info?

Comment: `soup.find_all('li', attrs={'class':'m-PromoList__a-ListItem'})` will get all of them

Comment: cool, now can you accept my answer and help me gather some points ;)

Comment: Is there somewhere other than the beautiful soup website where you're taught to use beautiful soup?

Comment: A better way to scrape website is using scrapy. Its fast, efficient and easy.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways you can achieve the same. Here is another approach using `css selector`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get('http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/a-z')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
for item in soup.select(".m-PromoList__a-ListItem a"):
    print("Item_Title: {}\nItem_Link: {}\n".format(item.text,item['href']))
```

Partial result:

```
Item_Title: "16 Bean" Pasta E Fagioli
Item_Link: //www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/ina-garten/16-bean-pasta-e-fagioli-3612570

Item_Title: "16 Bean" Pasta e Fagioli
Item_Link: //www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/ina-garten/16-bean-pasta-e-fagioli-1-3753755

Item_Title: "21" Apple Pie
Item_Link: //www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/21-apple-pie-recipe-1925900
```